# Python module installed but not being recognized

Tags: python, pip, jira

So I installed the Jira python package for a project I am working on. I import it using the command:

```
from jira.client import JIRA
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 9, in <module>
    from jira.client import JIRA
ImportError: No module named jira.client
```

When I tried to see where jira is, it tells me it doesn't exist. After trying to install it, it throws this...

```
csd-user@62-qa-driver12 ~]$ which jira
/usr/bin/which: no jira in (/opt/clearsky/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/csd-user/.local/bin:/home/csd-user/bin)
[csd-user@62-qa-driver12 ~]$ pip install jira
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jira in /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tlslite>=0.4.4 in /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jira)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.6.0 in /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jira)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests-toolbelt in /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jira)
 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests-oauthlib>=0.3.3 in /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jira)
 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9.0 in  /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jira)
 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ordereddict in /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jira)
 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauthlib>=0.6.2 in /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.3.3->jira)
[csd-user@62-qa-driver12 ~]$ pip install --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
/opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: 
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail.
     For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.

InsecurePlatformWarning
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /opt/clearsky/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I have zero idea how to deal with this. I did install Jira successfully once and then this happens. Upgrading pip didn't work.

Comment: have you tried `python -m pip install jira`? The `pip` script does not necessarily belong to the python interpreter you are currently using.

Comment: @cel that isn't working. pip not installed apparently. Even though I can see it when I say which pip. I also tried sudo yum install pip and python get-pip.py

Comment: The correct install command is `sudo yum install python-pip`